# How to solve this system of non linear trigonometric equations.

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

How to solve this system of non linear trigonometric equations:

$$\begin{align}
A\sin\theta_1+\phantom{5\omega}B\sin\theta_2 &=P \tag{1}\\
2A\sin\theta_1+\phantom{\omega}5B\sin\theta_2 &=Q \tag{2}\\
A\omega\cos\theta_1+\phantom{5}B\omega\cos\theta_2 &=0 \tag{3}\\
2A\omega\cos\theta_1+5B\omega\cos\theta_2 &=0 \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

$A$, $B$, $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ are variables, and $\omega$ is a constant.

Can you at least give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Note that $\omega$ in equations $3$ and $4$ is of no use. That is, if it is nonzero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following assumptions are to be made: $A, B,$ and $\omega \ne 0$
$$\left(2\right)-2\times\left(1\right)\space\space\space\space 3B\sin\theta_2=Q-2P$$
$$\left(4\right)-2\times\left(3\right)\space\space\space\space\space 3B\cos\theta_2=0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$$
$$5\times\left(1\right)-\left(2\right)\space\space\space\space 3A\sin\theta_1=5P-Q$$
$$5\times\left(3\right)-\left(4\right)\space\space\space\space\space 3A\cos\theta_1=0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$$
This is the hint you requested. Now please proceed.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:

Use $(3)$ to simplify $(4)$ and $(1)$ to simplify $(2)$. Square and add to eliminate $\theta_2$. Can you proceed?